# Getting error - {Animated node with tag 2 does not exists} when running react native expo on android device

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, runtime-error

This is the code of the first screen (Splash Screen) -

```
import React from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Dimensions,
    StyleSheet,
    StatusBar,
    Image,
} from "react-native";
import * as Animatable from "react-native-animatable";
// import LinearGradient from "react-native-linear-gradient";
import MaterialIcons from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons";
import { useTheme } from "@react-navigation/native";

const SplashScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { colors } = useTheme();

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar backgroundColor="#009387" barStyle="light-content" />
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Animatable.Image
                    animation="bounceIn"
                    duraton="1500"
                    source={require("../assets/logo.png")}
                    style={styles.logo}
                    resizeMode="stretch"
                />
            </View>
            <Animatable.View
                style={[
                    styles.footer,
                    {
                        backgroundColor: colors.background,
                    },
                ]}
                animation="fadeInUpBig"
            >
                <Text
                    style={[
                        styles.title,
                        {
                            color: colors.text,
                        },
                    ]}
                >
                    Stay connected with everyone!
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Sign in with account</Text>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SignInScreen")}
                    >
                        {/* <LinearGradient
                            colors={["#08d4c4", "#01ab9d"]}
                            style={styles.signIn}
                        > */}
                        <Text style={styles.textSign}>Get Started</Text>
                        <MaterialIcons
                            name="navigate-next"
                            color="#fff"
                            size={20}
                        />
                        {/* </LinearGradient> */}
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </Animatable.View>
        </View>
    );
};

export default SplashScreen;

const { height } = Dimensions.get("screen");
const height_logo = height * 0.28;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#009387",
    },
    header: {
        flex: 2,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
    },
    footer: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
        borderTopRightRadius: 30,
        paddingVertical: 50,
        paddingHorizontal: 30,
    },
    logo: {
        width: height_logo,
        height: height_logo,
    },
    title: {
        color: "#05375a",
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: "bold",
    },
    text: {
        color: "grey",
        marginTop: 5,
    },
    button: {
        alignItems: "flex-end",
        marginTop: 30,
    },
    signIn: {
        width: 150,
        height: 40,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        borderRadius: 50,
        flexDirection: "row",
    },
    textSign: {
        color: "white",
        fontWeight: "bold",
    },
});
```

This is the full error I am getting after running it on my android device -

[image: Animated node with tag 2 does not exists]

I am finding trouble writing all the error code from a screenshot so I added it as image. It will be kind of you if you just check image for more info about the error.

Hope you can help. I am a starter so any help is super useful and appreciatable. Thanks a lot in advance.

Please help.

Please tell any suggestions you have.

Note: I have not tested the code on IOS device.